# Add markers to Mapbox from CSV file

Tags: android, csv, url, addition, markers

I have some data points in a csv file located on my website (www.mysite.com/csv_report/myfile.csv) as below:

subject,report_by,Lat,Long

I want to show each of data points as independent markers on Mapbox. I found a solution in Mapbox samples about add single marker but nothing found about multiple markers.

Please help me to find the best way to solve my issue.

Thanks a lot
Zare

Answer (score 1):

Your best joice would probably be to use the by Mapbox provides sources/layers functionality.

The source(s) contain your datapoints, where as the layers you can think of it like an style sheet for HTML. It containes information about how the datapoints are gonna look like.

For creating the layer, you have different options depending on how you want the markers to look like. If you want to show your own icon you have to use a SymbolLayer, but there are many more (CircleLayer for displaying points/circles, ...)

For creating the source use something like the following

```
style.addLayer(
    new SymbolLayer(YOUR_LAYER_ID_STRING, YOUR_SOURCE_ID_STRING)
                    .withProperties(
                        // here you can define things like the icon
                        // icon color
                        // icon size
                        // ... many more. Have a look at the Property class
                    )
);
```

You can also style your items based on values of your items. Its called data driven styling in Mapbox. See my other answer to maybe get a bit more understanding.

For creating the source use something like the following

```
ArrayList<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();

Iterate over your CSV items {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("subject_key", item.subjectValue);
    jsonObject.addProperty("report_key", item.reportByValue);

    features.add(Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(item.getLat(), item.getLon()), jsonObject);
}

FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(features);
style.addSource(new GeoJsonSource(YOUR_SOURCE_ID_STRING, featureCollection, new GeoJsonOptions()));
```

You can furthermore have click listeners to catch clicks on the markers (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/click-on-a-single-layer/).